# Draft.js not showing anything in rails app view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, draftjs

I've installed draft-js using npm and yarn. The installation seems to have been completed fine. Below is the code for my react component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
    }
  }

  onChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Editor
          editorState={this.state.editorState}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyEditor;
```

Trying to render it in my view using react-rails gem helper as below:

```
<%= react_component("MyEditor") %>
```

Still don't see anything in my view. Don't see any errors in the browser developer console or rails console. Using Webpacker for packaging.

Any suggestions out there?

Comment: Can't believe no one seems interested in draft.js :)